# OpenID Library for PHP 5.3

Tags: php, openid

Does anyone have openid working in a PHP 5.3 installation? None of the [libraries](http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries) I've tried seem to be working.

Comment: haven't ever used it personally, but supposedly Zend Framework 1.9's Zend_Openid is compatible with 5.3 since the whole release is supposed to be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally got to fix the library... I explained everything [here](http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/60/janrain-s-php-openid-library-fixed-for-php-5-3-and-how-i-did-it) (you can also download the php-openid library after my changes).

I needed to do what Paul Tarjan suggested but, also, I needed to modify the `Auth_OpenID_detectMathLibrary` and add the `static` keyword to a lot of functions. After that It seems to work perfectly although it is not an ideal solution... I think that someone should rewrite the whole library in PHP 5...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to remove all the of pass-by-reference elements in php-openid.

change

```
foo(&$param)
```

to

```
foo($param)
```

and the library should work again.

Comment: That, and the suggestions in [this ticket](http://trac.openidenabled.com/trac/ticket/337) of openidenabled.com make the library work partially. However, that will not fix the library completely and the authentication with Google will not work.

Comment: google logins seem to work for me with this change : http://paulisageek.com/openidavatar/

Comment: Ok, I finally fixed it... I explain everything in my answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

[Zend_OpenId](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html) is compatible with PHP 5.3, however it only supports OpenID 1.1 and will not work with Google (which uses OpenID 2.0). Janrain's OpenID system normally available via http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/ is the one I'm using for my PHP 5 application (the OpenID enabled site is currently slightly down for maintenance today) - it is also one of the more popular PHP OpenID implementations (only small snag is that it uses temporary files for the OpenID sessions - making getting it working on a multi-server environment slightly tricky).

Comment: Right, I'm not going to use an openid 1.1 provider. And Janrain was NOT working on PHP 5.3 for me. Does it work for you?